# TypeError/IndexError when iterating with a for loop, and referencing lst[i]

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, typeerror, index-error

I'm using a `for` loop to iterate over a list like this:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i in lst:
    print(lst[i])
```

But there must be something wrong with that, because it throws the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(lst[i])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

And if I try the same thing with a list of integers, it throws an `IndexError` instead:

```
lst = [5, 6, 7]
for i in lst:
    print(lst[i])
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 4, in <module>
    print(lst[i])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What's wrong with my `for` loop?

Comment: Questions like this come up fairly regularly, and I never could find a proper duplicate for them. So I made my own. If anyone knows a better one, please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's `for` loop iterates over the *values* of the list, not the *indices*:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i in lst:
    print(i)

# output:
# a
# b
# c
```

That's why you get an error if you try to index `lst` with `i`:

```
>>> lst['a']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

```
>>> lst[5]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Many people use indices to iterate out of habit, because they're used to doing it that way from other programming languages. **In Python you rarely need indices.** Looping over the values is much more convenient and readable:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for val in lst:
    print(val)

# output:
# a
# b
# c
```

And if you *really* need the indices in your loop, you can use the [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for i, val in enumerate(lst):
    print('element {} = {}'.format(i, val))

# output:
# element 0 = a
# element 1 = b
# element 2 = c
```

Comment: can even use `print("element %d  = %c"%(i,val))`

Comment: Also worth pointing out that **the terrible choice of variable name `for i in lst` is half the problem: it (wrongly) suggests it's an index, not a list element**. Better to write `for x in lst` or `for el in lst` or `for lx in lst`. Noone would ever try to write `lst[el]` ; the choice of name makes very obvious it ain't no index, and protects you from writing nonsense. You should show a few examples of Good vs Bad for-loop variable names.

Comment: @smci That's a good point, but I'd rather not bloat my answer with "what not to do" examples. I think once people understand what `for` loops do, they'll choose more suitable variable names anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Corollary: name your loop-variable to avoid confusion and bad code

- `for i in lst` is a TERRIBLE name

  - suggests it's an index, and that we can and should do `lst[i]`, which is nonsense, and throws error
  - names like i, j, n are typically only used for indices
- GOOD: `for x in lst`, `for el in lst`, `for lx in lst`.

  - Noone would ever try to write `lst[el]`; the choice of name makes very obvious it ain't no index, and protects you from writing nonsense.

Summary:

- Python for-loop variables assume values from the list, not its indices
- usually you don't need the indices, but if you do, use `enumerate()` : `for i, x in enumerate(list): ...`
- usually better idiom to directly iterate over the list (not its indices, and lookup each entry)